# How to get High Availability if using SQL and a NAS?

Tags: sql, high-availability, network-attached-storage

In a scenario where we want to use a NAS as storage for a big (MS SQL) database, how would you handle the high availability if the mdf files are stored physically only in the NAS device?

Comment: If the database files are only stored on the NAS then you can't. You need to set up some type of HA cluster.

Comment: That's my question. What's the best practice? Or NAS and HA do not combine?

Comment: You could certainly use a NAS but you need more than one. There are a number of different ways you could do this. Look into SQL Server HA solutions, Google will help. - https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=sql%20server%20high%20availability

Comment: So is it that simple? just two NAS devices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted you will definetely need at least one more NAS to build truly HA environment. Then you connect them as DAS to each of the host, create shared storage across and configure Failover cluster. From that point, you' ll be able to go with SQL AAQ feature, for example. To make a storage pool, check some SDS solutions like HP VSE or StarWind. Not sure about HP http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/data-storage/free-vsa.html, but StarWind's free version can certainly do the job for you: https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free
But I would still recommend to check both of them.